# VBA Shell on mac tries to open the .sh file in text editor rather than executing it

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I tried to run code like the following in word macro on mac

resultcode = Shell("pathtosh/somescript.sh", vbHide)

However, it opens the file in the text editor rather than executing it. The sh file has a single line command to execute a python file.

Comment: can you change the file to make it executable using chmod from the command line?

Comment: I tried chmod +x somescript.sh. After that it still tries to open the file...